# Vim keyboard shortcuts changed, how to revert to normal?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, keymapping

I used to use ctrl+left/right to navigate between words (I know I'm supposed to use b/e etc in vim, but...). But starting today, ctrl+left/right deletes the next 4 lines! I tried disabling my plugins one by one, but it didn't help. I also have triple checked my vimrc file -- nothing there.

Where else are vim key mappings defined? Is there any plugin that can cause this behaviour? The only recent change that I have made has been changing my colour scheme to Solarized.

Thanks

Edit: I found the cause. It's a line I have added to .bashrc to have 256 colors. The line is export TERM="screen-256color-bce" . I still don't know how to correct it (aside from removing the line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of a line I have added to .bashrc to have 256 colors in vim. The line is *export TERM="screen-256color-bce"*. I removed that line and instead added *set t_Co=256* to .vimrc before setting colorscheme. Now vim uses 256 colors and the key mappings work properly.

Answer (score 1):

`:verbose map` will show you all mappings and also where they were set from.
If you only want to see maps for specific mode (like normal, input, or visual), use `:verbose nmap`, `:verbose imap`, or `:verbose vmap`.

This also may be not because of Vim, but because of terminal application. Did you change therminal or its settings recently?

Comment: I installed Solarized colour scheme for gnome-terminal - https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized

Comment: Can't see anything for ctrl+arrows in :verbose map output. Is there a way to reset terminal key mappings? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Okay, so apparently my key mappings in vimrc for alt+left/right are deleting lines too now!